# Cassandra db restore database issue

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, cassandra-4.0

i'm trying to restore cassandra database keyspace but in restore time face some issues

ERROR ----------

```
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,415 CompactionTask.java:253 - Compacted (54c99bc0-9e38-11ee-9d67-b1104ddc5c94) 4 sstables to [/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/nb-89-big,] to level=0.  9.375KiB to 9.053KiB (~96% of original) in 120ms.  Read Throughput = 77.647KiB/s, Write Throughput = 74.979KiB/s, Row Throughput = ~414/s.  207 total partitions merged to 207.  Partition merge counts were {1:207, }. Time spent writing keys = 79ms
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,416 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/nb-87-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,418 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/nb-86-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,421 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/nb-88-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,424 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/nb-85-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,534 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/native/contract-6e4fb1303c2f11ee89779b5af69fb846/nb-15-big
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:2] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,534 CompactionTask.java:253 - Compacted (54d9ef70-9e38-11ee-9d67-b1104ddc5c94) 13 sstables to [/var/lib/cassandra/data/native/contract-6e4fb1303c2f11ee89779b5af69fb846/nb-16-big,] to level=0.  26.284KiB to 11.352KiB (~43% of original) in 131ms.  Read Throughput = 199.506KiB/s, Write Throughput = 86.162KiB/s, Row Throughput = ~290/s.  325 total partitions merged to 145.  Partition merge counts were {1:81, 2:4, 3:4, 4:56, }. Time spent writing keys = 66ms
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,536 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/native/contract-6e4fb1303c2f11ee89779b5af69fb846/nb-14-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,538 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/native/contract-6e4fb1303c2f11ee89779b5af69fb846/nb-2-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,540 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/native/contract-6e4fb1303c2f11ee89779b5af69fb846/nb-13-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,542 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/native/contract-6e4fb1303c2f11ee89779b5af69fb846/nb-3-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,544 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/native/contract-6e4fb1303c2f11ee89779b5af69fb846/nb-5-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,547 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/native/contract-6e4fb1303c2f11ee89779b5af69fb846/nb-4-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,549 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/native/contract-6e4fb1303c2f11ee89779b5af69fb846/nb-1-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,551 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/native/contract-6e4fb1303c2f11ee89779b5af69fb846/nb-6-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,553 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/native/contract-6e4fb1303c2f11ee89779b5af69fb846/nb-9-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,555 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/native/contract-6e4fb1303c2f11ee89779b5af69fb846/nb-8-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,557 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/native/contract-6e4fb1303c2f11ee89779b5af69fb846/nb-7-big
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2023-12-19 06:32:07,560 SSTable.java:127 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/native/contract-6e4fb1303c2f11ee89779b5af69fb846/nb-10-big
```

Errror 2nd -----------------------

```
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/10.0.4.31:7000-ff366fdf] 2023-12-19 05:32:48,902 StreamDeserializingTask.java:92 - [Stream channel: ff366fdf] stream operation from /10.0.4.31:34676 failed
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncStreamingInputPlus.reBuffer(AsyncStreamingInputPlus.java:119)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RebufferingInputStream.readByte(RebufferingInputStream.java:178)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:49)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamDeserializingTask.run(StreamDeserializingTask.java:59)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
ERROR [Stream-Deserializer-/10.0.4.31:7000-4dfa8412] 2023-12-19 05:32:48,902 StreamDeserializingTask.java:92 - [Stream channel: 4dfa8412] stream operation from /10.0.4.31:34680 failed
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncStreamingInputPlus.reBuffer(AsyncStreamingInputPlus.java:119)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RebufferingInputStream.readByte(RebufferingInputStream.java:178)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:49)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamDeserializingTask.run(StreamDeserializingTask.java:59)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

some time stram failed errorr
my all node are up

i try with restore with `sstableloader -d ip /home/data`
but all data not restore only 353 raws in my table but only 145 raws restore.

Comment: Welcome to Stack and Cassandra community! This may be a better question for [Stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassandra) as per [the community guidelines here](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/community.html#discussions). And, also this question lags many details. For e.g. at a minimum, you need to post the cluster topology, C* version, `nodetool status` output, what steps did you do to take backup and restore, console errors, stacktraces, etc., in order for someone to help assist you with this request.